# How to perform non-parametric test (e.g. Kruskal Wallis) on nested data in R

Tags: r, anova, biostatistics, kruskal-wallis-test

I have a dataset of non-parametric data that contains plant height at 16 sites, 4 of which are under treatment A, 4 under treatment B, 4 under C and 4 under D. Originally I performed a Krukal-Wallis Test followed by a Dunn's Test for plant height relative to treatment, but was told that to avoid pseudo-replication I should nest the data. I have now nested the data by treatment (using drplyr groupby()), but the Kruskal-Wallis test on R is confused by this and online forums I've read so far only mention how to test nested data with ANOVAs.

Any ideas either how to do a Kruskal-Wallis on nested data or any alternative tests that would work? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like what you might need is a mixed effects model with a fixed effect of treatment and a random effect of site. Hopefully a real statistician will provide more guidance on Cross Validated.

Comment: Why are you treating plant height as non-parametric? Was there a physical relationship among the sites that needs to be taken into account? Please show how you would model the data if outcomes could be handled as continuous under usual ANOVA conditions; the specifics of the nesting aren't clear to me from this question. Please add this information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can get deleted. The more details you can present about the original experimental design and data collection, the better.